# How to access sharepoint resources files from Hive programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

i need to get resources from one resource file of the sharepoint folder 12. The method `HttpContext.GetGlobalResources()` seems not to work for that ...
How can i do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ... `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(...)` did the work !

Thanks.